# Обратиться к свойству "родитель" из сведений устройства в диспетчере задач

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, windows-7, visual-basic

Добрый день,

не могу найти способ получить через vb .net строку "родитель", которую видно в диспетчере устройств, в свойствах оборудования, во вкладке сведения, в выпадающем списке "свойство".

Пробовал через классы:
Win32_:
Win32_PnPEntity
Win32_SerialPort
и другие

В этих классах есть многие свойства, доступные выпадающем списке, но "родитель" нету.

Немного о проблеме. Есть оборудование, которое подключается к компу через usb, но внутри себя оно содержит переход com_port - usb. Установка происходит через специальный драйвер. То есть я вижу устройство и в usb портах и в com портах.

Благодарю за внимание!

Comment: [Более подробно](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300669/get-the-string-with-parent-of-device#comment67860123_40300669)